# Expected value of exactly one ball in n balls in n boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$n$ balls are placed randomly into $n$ boxes. Let $N_1$ be the number of boxes with exactly one ball. Find $E(N_1)$. Show it is about $\frac{n}{e}$

I tried breaking it into indicator variables, where

$N_1 = L_1 + L_2 + ... + L_n$
Where $L_i = 1$ if box i has ball 1, and $0$ otherwise,

Then (I think) $P(L_i = 1) = \frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$

And since this is a binomial distribution, $E(N_1) = n\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$

But I'm not sure how to get this to $\frac{n}{e}$

Comment: Are $N$ and $n$ the same?  It looks like they should be from your title, but they look different in your text.

Comment: No. I'll change that. Thanks

Comment: I believe that $P(L_i=1)=n\times \frac 1n\times \left( \frac {n-1}n\right)^{n-1}$, which tends to $e$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $P(L_i)=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$ because you choose a ball to put in box $i$ ($n$ ways).  Then chooses boxes for the other $n-1$ balls, but avoiding box $i$ ($(n-1)^{n-1}$ ways).  The denominator is $n^n$ for all possible distribution choices.

So $P(L_i)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n}{1-\frac1n}$.

For large $n$, $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ gives a well-known approximation for $\frac1e$.
[This is based on $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n=e^x.$]

Can you take it from there.